# Calculate the index of a given number within a sorted set

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Not sure if this question should be on Math-Overflow or here, so will try here first:

Suppose we are given a number with N 1s and M 0s.

There are (M+N)!/(M!*N!) different such numbers, that can be sorted in a countable set.

For example, the sorted set of all numbers with 2 ones and 3 zeros, is:

- `0 00011`
- `1 00101`
- `2 00110`
- `3 01001`
- `4 01010`
- `5 01100`
- `6 10001`
- `7 10010`
- `8 10100`
- `9 11000`

How can we efficiently calculate the index of a given number within the corresponding set?

Note: the input to this question is **only** the number, and **not** the entire (corresponding) set.

Comment: You have two options: 1. Prove that there is some system in how a value corresponds to an index, or 2. Search for it. The first is most likely a math problem, the second is a binary search.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: the input to this question is **only** the number (**not** the entire set, which can be inferred from it).

Comment: (M+N)!/(M!*N!) ? I think there is only C(N, M + N) number, which means to choose N positions for '1' from M + N positions

Comment: @Pham Trung: In the example above, N=2, M=3, and there are (2+3)!/(2!*3!)=10 options.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to compute. Would you give an example (input and expected output) please ?

Comment: Oh, yes, actually two formulas are the same thing :)

Comment: @hivert: Given 10010, I want to calculate the index of this number within the sorted set of all numbers containing 2 zeros and 3 ones (BTW, as shown in my question, the answer for 10010 is 7).

Comment: Ok so my code should be correct.

Answer (score 6):

Let `choose (n, k) = n! / k! / (n-k)!`.

Observe the following structure of your sorted set:

`0 0|0011
    1 0|0101
    2 0|0110
    3 0|1001
    4 0|1010
    5 0|1100
      ------
    6 1|0001
    7 1|0010
    8 1|0100
    9 1|1000`

In the sorted set, there are `choose (N + M, M)` numbers (binary strings of length `N + M`) in total.
First go the numbers starting by a zero, and there are `choose (N + M-1, M-1)` of them. Then go the numbers starting by a one, and there are `choose (N-1 + M, M)` of them. Each of these two sections is also sorted.

So, if your number b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>k</sub> starts with a zero (b<sub>1</sub> = 0), its index in the sorted set is the same as index of b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>k</sub> in the sorted set of all binary strings of `N` ones and `M-1` zeroes. If it starts with a one (b<sub>1</sub> = 1), its index in the sorted set is the same as index of b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>k</sub> in the sorted set of all binary strings of `N-1` ones and `M` zeroes, **plus** the total number of binary strings starting with a zero, which is `choose (N + M-1, M-1)`.

In this way, you recursively descent to subproblems involving suffixes of your original binary string, increasing the sought number by some amount whenever you meet a 1. In the end, you come to an empty binary string which clearly is the one and only string consisting of 0 zeroes and 0 ones.

Comment: Thank you both (you and @hivert) for the detailed answers!

Answer (score 5):

This is called **ranking** in combinatorial algorithms. Here is a C function that does that for you:

```
unsigned long rank_choose(unsigned long n, unsigned long k, unsigned long c) {
  unsigned long res = 0;
  for (; n > 0; n--) {
    if (c & 1) { res += binomial(n-1, k); k--;}
    c >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

It assume that you have a function `binomial(n, k)` which compute the coefficient `n!/k!/(n-k)!`. Be careful, the solution I propose here use an **endianess reversed** representation:

```
const int m = 5, n = 2;
int k = 12;
std::cout << std::bitset<m>(k) << " " << rank_choose(m, n, k) << std::endl;
k = 9;
std::cout << std::bitset<m>(k) << " " << rank_choose(m, n, k) << std::endl;
```

Returns:

```
01100 2
01001 7
```

Here is a solution with the other endianess:

```
unsigned long rank_choose_rev(unsigned long n, unsigned long k, unsigned long c) {
  unsigned long res = 0, mask = 1<<(n-1);
  for (; n > 0; n--) {
    if (c & mask) { res += binomial(n-1, k); k--;}
    mask >>= 1;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Then

```
01100 5
01001 3
```

**Note** : The algorithms is nicely described by @Gassa below (+1 to him).

Comment: Thanks! I have **one** input number, and this function takes **three** input arguments. Can you please clarify?

Comment: You have to input m (n in my code) and n (k in my code) too.

Comment: OK, so my `N` and `M` are your `n` and `k`, and my input number is your `c`?

Comment: Something not right, n in your code should be (M + N), which means choosing k number '1' in the last n -1 position

Comment: Thank you both (you and @Gassa) for the detailed answers!

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain one solution with the help of an example. Say there are `3 ones` and `3 zeroes` and we have to find the index of `010110`

The first one from left is at the second position. Hence all number that have double zeroes at their right shall be less than this number:

```
00---- (C(4,3)) = 4
```

Now place this one at its position and move to the next one. Next one is at position 4. Hence all the following numbers shall be less than the candidate:

```
0100-- (C(2,2)) = 1
```

Now place this one at its position and move to the next one. Next one is at position 5. Hence all the following numbers shall be less than the candidate:

```
01010- (C(1,1)) = 1

Hence the number of numbers less than the candidate = 4 + 1 + 1 = 6

000111
001011
001101
001110
010011
010101
010110
```