# Algorithm for finding the index of given permutation of a multiset permutation

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the most efficient algorithm to find the index of given permutation of a multiset permutations of '0' and '1'.

Ex: Given {0, 0, 1, 1}. All possible permutations in ascending order are: {0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100}. These elements are indexed as 0 -> 6. Given s = 0110, the result is 2.

This question is quite similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013373/finding-the-index-of-a-given-permutation), but his question is on proper set (e.g., {1, 2, 3}). Another similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131497/find-the-index-of-a-given-permutation-in-the-sorted-list-of-the-permutations-of), but the answer is O(N!). The following code is my try, but it is not efficient too (O(N!)).

```
def find_index(s, pos): # s is the given permutation, pos is the index list of '1' in s
    d_index = 0
    c = 0
    for i in range (len(pos)-1, -1, -1):
        d_index = d_index + 1
        if (len-1-pos[i] >= d_index):
            c_i = c_i + Combination (d_index, len-1-pos[i])
    if (c == 0):
        return 0
    return c
```

Comment: The second link, the time complexity is not O(N!)

Comment: So this only deals with binary numbers?

Comment: @user2963623: yes, only binary numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219074/calculate-the-index-of-a-given-number-within-a-sorted-set/22219424#22219424 this question is already discussed here.

Comment: @PhamTrung: thank you. The answer of Gassa seems to be similar to me. I wonder is there a more efficient way.

Comment: I don't think so, his answer is O(N) with N is number of bit, I think it is optimal.

Comment: But doesn't that require a sorted list of all the permutations?

Comment: @PhamTrung: thank you very much. I am trying Glassa and hivert methods on my tests.

Comment: @user2963623 No, it just iterate from bit to bit of the current permutation. For example, you have 2 bit 1 and 2 bit 0, so 
  if you see the first 1 bit at position 4, so this current permutation should be greater than C(3,2) other permutations (chosing 2 position to be 1 in the last 3 position)

Comment: @PhamTrung: I am trying to find the opposite algorithm (find permutation of a set of '0' and '1', given index). Could you please kindly show me. I actually asked this question in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506460/algorithm-for-finding-multiset-permutation-given-lexicographic-index], the answer is O(N^2). Is there any way which takes O(N)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This approach simply loops over all the binary numbers till the given number s and checks if each number has the required number of 0s and 1s, if it does then increments a counter.

```
s = '0110'     # input
count_0 = s.count('0')
count_1 = s.count('1')
l = len(s)
index = 0
for i in xrange(0, int(s,2)):
    binary = ('{:0%sb}'%l).format(i) #converts integer into binary of length l bits
    if binary.count('0') == count_0 and binary.count('1') == count_1: index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First solve this problem : Given a multiset, find the `n`-th permutation. You can do this recursively. Let `F(S, n)` be a function which computes two things : the `n`-th permutation of multiset `S` and the total number of permutations.

```
`F(S, ~).total = F(S-{0}, ~).total + F(S-{1}, ~).total`.
```

If   `F(S-{0}, ~).total < n`, `F(S, n) = 0 . F(S-{0}, n)`
else `F(S, n) = 1 . F(S-{1}, n - F(S-{0}, ~).total)`

Armed with `F(S, n)`, you can do a binary search to find the index of your required permutation. The range for this binary search will be `[0, N!]`.

Let's add up the runtimes : if `S` in your initial set and `|S| = N`, computing all the `F(s, n)`s requires `O(N)` time per state, assuming you are memoizing(this accounts for the fact that hashing your state might not be `O(1)`). The number of states is `O(N*2^N)`. The binary search takes `O(log N!) = O(N log N)`, giving you a runtime of `O(N*2^N)`.

Answer (score 0):

why is it not posible to use a list?

```
s = '0110'
p = ['0011', '0101', '0110', '1001', '1010', '1100']
p.index(s)
```

To make the data storage even more efficient you could use them as integers:

```
s = 0b0110
p = [0b0011, 0b0101, 0b0110, 0b1001, 0b1010, 0b1100]
```

Indexing works the same way.